# Algorithm to solve nonsquare system of equations with constraints on coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-optimization, constraints

I'm making a fridge app which will use the known data (the amount of servings remaining for each food item and the amount in grams of carbs, proteins, fats in each serving of a given food item) in order to suggest a combination of food items that the user has that will be close to the user's desired amounts in grams of carbs, proteins, fats per day.

I have a nonlinear system of equations Ax = b.

The A matrix is 3 rows tall and m columns wide.

The b matrix is 3 rows by 1 column.

The x matrix is m rows by 1 column.

Both A and b are known. The goal is to find a value for x that will make Ax as close to b as possible.

numservings is a matrix where numservings[i] is the number of servings available of the food item with index i.

The constraints are that each coefficient c_i has to be integer and has to have value 0, 1, 2, up to numservings[i]. These constraints are easy to understand but they would make solving the system harder.

I was thinking of using Least Squares to find an approximate solution.
This added constraint will make things harder.

1. How can I make an algorithm to suggest the user eat this number of servings for food item 1, another number of servings for food item 2, and so on?
2. How can I most accurately solve a nonsquare linear system of equations with constraints on coefficients like I described above?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler_diet